# Bash replace middle decimal point with a dash

Tags: bash

I'm looking to change a variable with format 8.0.3.0 to 8.0-3.0 in a bash script

So it's always the middle decimal point to a dash

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I would use awk rather than the built-in bash string handling.  Split on '.' and then rebuild the string.

Comment: Can you let us know more cases, what if the digits are more than 4? How should the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), like this:

```
v="8.0.3.0"
echo "${v%*.*.*}-${v#*.*.}"
```

Comment: Exactly what I had copy pasted, about to post it as an answer. But it fails, for 5 digit nos, `string="8.0.3.2.1"; echo "${v%*.*.*}-${v#*.*.}" 8.0-3.0`. Didn't post it , waiting for OP's clarification on it!

Comment: The OP didn't provided a schema for 5 digit versions so far nor didn't they requested that. Also it is pretty unlikely that they want a general solution to any kind of version number because version numbering is  a very project specific thingy.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed` you can suffix a replacement with the occurence of the match you want to replace :

```
$ echo "a.b.c.d" | sed 's/\./-/2'
a.b-c.d
```

Comment: This worked great but I accepted the other solution as it didn't require running echo or sed - thanks though

Comment: @MikeLothian Sure, no problem. Thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of data to handle, it may be worth trying this solution which is not as concise but avoids calling an external program, using internal matching, so may be faster.

```
string=8.0.3.0
if
  [[ $string =~ ^([0-9])[.]([0-9])[.]([0-9])[.]([0-9])$ ]]
then
  newstring="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}.${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
else
  echo "ERROR: no match on $string"
fi
```

Comment: Just use the exit code of the `test` directly `[[ $string =~ ^([0-9])[.]([0-9])[.]([0-9])[.]([0-9])$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}.${BASH_REMATCH[4]}" || echo "whatever"`

Comment: @Inian One can do that but in this case (1) it would become much less readable and (2) would become even mode unreadable once error handling has to be fitted on the same line.  I tend to use the logical operators when the resulting expression easily fits on one line (which is often), and use an `if` block otherwise.

Comment: Also, `newstring` temporary variable is not needed!

Comment: Shell is typically slower in text processing than pretty much any other solution. The cost of forking is negligible.

Comment: @Inian Of course, if the user does not want to keep the old value, or just wants to print the result, the new variable is not required.

Comment: @123  This is highly dependent on the use case.  For low amounts of data, avoiding the external call is faster but probably not significant.  For high amounts of data, if you can do it all with one call to `sed` or another utility, it will in all likelihood be faster.  But if for some reason you need to call an external program once for each iteration, then the shell-only solution will probably win.  The best way if to perform tests if performance really matters.

Comment: Please give me an example where the shell is notably faster at text manipulation as i can't think of any.

Comment: @123 I put the code for both the `sed` version shown above and my proposed solution in a loop with 1000 iterations.  On my machine, the `sed` version takes a little over 1 second, while the Bash-only version takes less than 0.15 second.  This is with an invocation of `sed` for each loop.  The@123 simple `sed` solution (without a loop) is less than 0.05 second, unexpectedly the fastest.  Please note that this is exactly what my previous comment alluded to (for high iteration count single external command is fastest, Bash-only second, and external command in loop typically slowest).

Comment: @123  My general point is, if you only need stream manipulation and can do it with a single external command, this will often be best.  But if you need to manipulate each line of data and do something else aside from printing on screen (or redirecting), shell programming may not be that bad, will often beat calling an external program once per iteration, and allows sharing of variables in the same scope as the rest of the script (often useful).

Comment: In what situation would you ever be forced to use a loop in bash for string manipulation though?

Comment: @123 Let's see...  Say, I have config files for backup procedures, and each line corresponds to a specific action.  I need to read that line, analyze it, and launch the corresponding backup action, with logging and notification.  Would I try to have `sed` or `awk` actually control backups while being streamed the config file on stdin, while taking care of reacting to errors and performing email notifications?  I don't think so.  Maybe you would say this is not "string manipulation", but I will still want do parse the config data in the shell.  I do a lot of these scripts.

Comment: You can just source config files if key value pairs. If not then why would you have a file containing actions and not just run the file?

Comment: @123  You can approach things with the idea that string manipulation should not be done in the shell ever, and design everything around that idea.  You will have a solution that works, but in some cases you will have to shoehorn a round-shaped need in a square-shaped hole.  I cannot convey in a few lines why I use shell string manipulation in some cases, but in the end everything is an engineering tradeoff involving portability, dependencies, performance, ease of configuration, security risks, programming language mismatch constraints...  It is case-by-case, I do not see it as black and white.

Comment: You can do string manipulation in bash. It makes sense to do so for variables. It doesn't make sense to do so from a file. Also not sure how my above suggestion is shoehorned as it is both clearer and quicker than using a loop and still uses only basic bash functionality. I honestly can't see any way it would be superior to use a shell loop to read a config file.

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is a choice

```
awk '$0 = gensub( /\./, "-", 2 )' file
8.0-3.0
```